# Passing xml parameter through java to stored procedure in sql server2008

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure which has input parameter type XML and which updates the database based on the xml tag values.

```
create procedure xxx @vari XML
```

Now I want to call the stored procedure from java.
I have created an xml string by looping and the xml looks something like this:

```
<root>
<file>
<file_name>D:\Data_Files\Data_Files\PDFDocuments\LWD Report.pdf</file_name>
<keyword>Resistivity</keyword>
<wordcount>17</wordcount>
</file>
<root>
```

then i have created java.sql.SQLXML object and called procedure like this

```
SQLXML xmlval=dbConnection.createSQLXML();
xmlval.setString(sb.toString());
callable=dbConnection.prepareCall("{CALL PARSEXML (?)}");
callable.setObject(1, xmlval);
callable.execute();
```

but the tables are not getting updated.
I have the same procedure in the management studio and it is working fine and updating the table.

My question is why this is not happening through java.

Answer (score 0):

We experiencing all kind of problem when dealing with XML for both MSSQL and Oracle.  These drivers can't handle it, especially when it come to large data.  We use NVARCHAR(MAX)/CLOB to solve this.  Simply have the stored proc receive it and do a simple string to XML conversion and this work great for us.

Comment: i had set sutocommit to false in my java so the table dint get updated now it's working fine